# Cron job with shell script

Tags: shell, hadoop, cron

i am trying to run a shell script using cronjob after every 2 minutes. I opened my terminal then typed

> crontab-e

once i execute this command i am writing my command

> */2 * * * * /home/test/test/test.sh

but i am getting an error as

> E486: Pattern not found: 2 * * * *

please help as i am new to this and i don't know why it is happening.
If you give me any links and code on hwo to execute cronjob it would help.

Comment: Check debugging crontab in http://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info

Comment: @fedorqui am i following the correct procedure to run cronjob ?

Comment: Yes, you are. `crontab -e` and then save it. Now it is a matter of checking what can cause the error. Probably using full paths and also adding the interpreter will solve it --> `*/2 * * * * /bin/bash /home/test/test.sh`

Comment: @fedorqui can you provide me one sample. i have seen in few examples they are writing the command as 2 * * * * path, where as i have written like */2 * * * * path, is this proper way ?

Comment: @IndranilGanguly: Once you run `crontab -e`, do you get a file opened in editor? You need to enter this `*/2 * * * * /home/test/test.sh` in that file and save it. From the error, it looks like you have entered the above line at the command prompt.

Comment: Check [crontab.guru](http://crontab.guru/#*/2_*_*_*_*) When you say `2` it will be minute `2`. When you say `*/2` it will be every other minute. Also very true what @Fazlin says: do use `crontab -e` (that is `crontab` + space + `-e`) and then, when in the text editor, write that command.

Comment: when i run crontab -e i am getting this : "/tmp/crontab.W4sMam" 0L, 0C  i dont know what it is

Comment: yes i am using crontab -e command and there i am writing my command.

Comment: Check this, it may resolve ur issue  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20942074/modify-directory-crontab-looks-in-for-crontab-file

Comment: And do you save this file later on? For example, if `VISUAL=vi crontab -e` you are editing with `vi`, so after writing the line then exit with `:wq` to store it.

Comment: @fedorqui when i write the command and then press enter i am getting that error. so not able to save it.

Comment: This is because you are not in the write mode in `vi`. For this you first have to type `i`. Write that line and then type Esc followed by `:wq` to store the file. Better check a `vi` manual also, since this is basic usage. Otherwise, set another editor you feel more comfortable with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, the following error:

> E486: Pattern not found: 2 * * * *

Was caused because you were not editing properly. That is, you were saying `crontab -e` correctly and then you were entering in `vi`. Instead of going into the insert mode, you would directly type `*/2 * * * * /home/test/test/test.sh`, which `vi` would try to perform as a command, which is not.

So what you have to do is to press <kbd>i</kbd> to enter in the write mode. And then, just then, write `*/2 * * * * /home/test/test/test.sh`. Finally, save the file by saying <kbd>:wq</kbd>.

In case other problems occur in your cronjob, you may want to check the "Debugging crontab" section in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/crontab/info.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to show it in more detail:

1. `crontab -e`
2. <kbd>i</kbd>
3. `* * * * * cd path/to/your/project && command`
4. <kbd>ESC</kbd>
5. `:wq`
6. <kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Please check the link in the correctly marked answer above for learning more about crontab.

Comment: nice ! i upvoted your solution. if you find my question useful kindly upvote it.